# How to add Edit, Delete and Search functionality in single view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I'm new to `MVC`.

on MSDN i've studied that there should be folder in `view` with the same name of `controller`. For every `Action Method` in the `controller` we have to create a `View` in the same folder.

**I'm creating a test application in which:**

I have a `homeController` with an `Index ActionMethod`. Corresponding to it i have a `View` in `View/home/Index`, which simply show the listing of the employees.

I know i can add a `[HTTP POST] Index ActionMethod` in the `homeController`.

But i want to add the `Delete` and `Search` functionality on the view. So that a user can search the employees with there name and can delete an employee on the same page.

I don't know how can i move ahead for this functionality.

Still i'm using this code.

**`homeController`**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.text = "Records Listing";
        var q = from p in objEmp.tbemployees select p;
        return View(q);
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
        @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication6.Models.tbemployee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>@ViewBag.text</h1>
<table style="font-size:15px;">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Address
        </th>
        <th>
            Sallary
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr >
            <td style="padding:7px;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(mm => item.ename)
            </td>
            <td style="padding:7px;">
              @Html.DisplayFor(mm => item.eadd)
            </td>
            <td style="padding:7px;">
              @Html.DisplayFor(mm => item.esal)
            </td>
              <td style="padding:7px; color:Blue; text-decoration:underline;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.empno })
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the Delete you could add a column in the table that will invoke a controller action and pass it the current record id:

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding:7px;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(mm => item.ename)
    </td>
    <td style="padding:7px;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(mm => item.eadd)
    </td>
    <td style="padding:7px;">
        @Html.DisplayFor(mm => item.esal)
    </td>
    <td style="padding:7px; color:Blue; text-decoration:underline;">
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.empno })
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.empno })
    </td>
</tr>
```

and your Delete action:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    ... use the passed id to delete the record from the database
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

for the Edit functionality you could have a controller action that will fetch the record and render a view that will allow for editing:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var employee = objEmp.tbemployees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    if (employee == null)
    {
        // no employee with the specified id was found
        return new HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(employee);
}
```

and then you could have a corresponding `~/Views/Home/Edit.cshtml` view:

```
@model Employee
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ename)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ename)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.eadd)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.eadd)
    </div>

    ...

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

and of course a corresponding action to update the record when this form is submitted:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
{
    ... update the employee record
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I have already created the edit functionality and view for it. As your code shows, i don't wanna add a new view for the delete. I wanna perform it on the same Index view.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code. Its working. One thing i wanna ask that, According to your code i have added a Delete `ActionMethond` in controller. But i haven't created an view for it. Isn't it required?

Comment: No, it is not required, because the Delete action redirects to the Index action. It doesn't return a View, so you don't need a view.

Comment: You could have a controller action that will render a view containing an HTML form with the corresponding fields you want to filter with. This HTML form could submit to a controller action that will filter the records and render the Index view with those filtered records: `return View("Index", filteredEmployees);`.

Comment: I would make sure the delete button is a post action. It's not a good practice to update entities using get

Answer (score 0):

You can add and implement a `Delete` action method in your controller. Then in your view, call `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.empno })`. This will return a hyperlink which links to your `Delete` method in the controller.

Comment: and what about the search functionality?